# Haskell - Lookup key in a user defined dictionary

Tags: haskell

If I have:

```
data Data = T | F
    deriving (Eq,  Show, Ord)

type PhoneBook = [(String, Data)] 

testBook :: Book
testBook = [("aT", T), ("bF", F)]
```

I'm trying to make a look up function, but because I'm using a user defined type it's throwing me off.  Any suggestions?  I'm trying:

```
lookup1 :: PhoneBook->String->Data
lookup1 [] key = Nothing
lookup1 ((k,v):xs) key = if key == k
                            then Just v
                            else lookup1 xs key
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a statement like `type Book = [(String, Answer)]` then `Book` is just a *synonym* for `[(String, Answer)]`. This means that you can replace `Book` with `[(String, Answer)]`  anywhere in your types without changing them. This means that looking up a value in a `Book` is *exactly* the same as looking up a value in a `[(String, Answer)]`.

Thus you can just use the normal `lookup` function to get the answer corresponding to a particular string.

Comment: ahhh!! that's helpful! grabbin a bite to eat then i'll be back to test it, tyvm!

Answer (score 8):

The code in the question compiles (and works!) once the type signature of the lookup1 function is changed to match its actual return type:

```
lookup1 :: Book -> String -> Maybe Answer
lookup1 [] key = Nothing
lookup1 ((k,v):xs) key = if key == k
                            then Just v
                            else lookup1 xs key
```

The *only* change is the return type of  `lookup1` , which is now **Maybe Answer** instead of **Answer** .